# Execute WITH statement inside a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

I have the following code:

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS
(

SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item) AS RowNumber
 from  dbo.fnSplit('1:2:3:5', ':')  
)

 select * from OrderedOrders where rownumber =2
```

I need to run this code inside a function, however I just can't make the syntax right. Here's how it is right now:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_INDICE_SPLIT]
    (@sInputList VARCHAR(8000),@sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000),@INDICE INT)

RETURN TABLE 


;WITH OrderedOrders AS
( 
SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item) AS RowNumber
 from  dbo.fnSplit(@sDelimiter, @INDICE)  
)
select ITEM from OrderedOrders where RowNumber=@INDICE
```

If I try to execute this, it gives me this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FN_INDICE_SPLIT, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'.
```

I've tried to do this in many ways, but I keep getting syntax errors and I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Why do you have to use a CTE? Just do `SELECT ITEM FROM (SELECT * ...) AS x WHERE RowNumber = @INDICE;`

Comment: @Aaron [To CTE or to subquery](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/2050/which-is-better-ctes-common-table-expressions-or-s.html) It's a style thing, but yes it would have prevented this question for the OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the semicolon before the WITH in a TABLE-VALUED FUNCTION.  Especially considering that you cannot even have multi-statements in a TVF, there's no reason for a statement delimiter to be present.

The correct form is `CREATE FUNCTION (...) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN <statement>`

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_INDICE_SPLIT]
    (@sInputList VARCHAR(8000),@sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000),@INDICE INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN
WITH OrderedOrders AS
( 
SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item) AS RowNumber
 from  dbo.fnSplit(@sDelimiter, @INDICE)  
)
select ITEM from OrderedOrders where RowNumber=@INDICE
GO
```

Comment: How do you do this if you're returning a `BIT` instead of a `TABLE`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use RETURN**S**

```
RETURNS TABLE
```